# Java library validate a URL and to strip out URL parameters from a string

Tags: java, regex, url

I am looking for a Java Library to validate a URL and to strip out certain parameters. The order of the parameters does not matter.

I was using regex but it is very slow. This method is called alot of times and needs to be fast.

Comment: What does "validate" mean to you?  Valid syntax?  What are you imagining will be faster than a regex?  Could the one you wrote just be inefficient?  Are you sure that this is truly a bottleneck in your application, or are you guilty of pre-mature optimization?  Do you have data that tells you that the validation is significantly slower?  If not, wait until you get some.

Comment: yes, it inefficient. I was matching the whole URL in regex. Valid means a url which is valid. So for example http$$://google.com would be invalid.

Comment: You didn't answer the data question.  Is your conclusion of inefficiency subjective or based on data?

Comment: Could you please post the relevant regex code that you are using?

Comment: Should be something like this: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/280-how-to-validate-urls-with-regular-expressions/.  I doubt that you'll do better.

Comment: You can use Apache Commons Validator - URLValidator which can be customized for schemes (HTTP, FTP, etc.) but won't work for `file://` scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Commons Validator includes `UrlValidator` class in `commons-validator-1.3.1.jar`. Following method is used to validate a given media resource locator (MRL) in VLCJ which is basically a URL. However, `UrlValidator` doesn't work for file-based URL (with `file://` scheme)

```
/**
 * Get a media resource locator (MRL) with the following valid conditions: 
 * <br/>(1) a non-URI file link
 * <br/>(2) a URI link with "file:" scheme  
 * <br/>(3) a URI link with non-"file:" scheme
 * <br/>  
 * @param mrl media resource locator (MRL)
 * @return valid MRL; otherwise return null
 */
private String validateMRL(final String mrl){
    String media = null;
    String newURI = mrl;
    URI uri = new File(mrl.trim()).toURI();
    try {
        String f = new File(mrl).getAbsolutePath();
        Outils.debugMessage("URI:" + f);
        if (FilenameUtils.equalsNormalized(newURI, f)){
            //this is a actual file link
            newURI = uri.toURL().toString();
            newURI = Outils.replaceAllString(newURI, "file:", "file://");
            Outils.debugMessage("NEW URI: " + newURI);
            media = newURI;
        }
        else if (!mrl.contains("file:")) {
            //this is not a file link or "file:" link
            if (mrl != null && mrl.length() > 0){

                String[] schemes = {"http", "https", "rtsp", "rtp", "udp", "mms", "mmsh"};

                UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator(schemes);

                if (urlValidator.isValid(newURI))
                    media = mrl.trim();
            }
        }
        else {
            media = mrl;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Outils.debugMessage("CURRENT: " + media);       
    return media;
}
```

Sorry that this function doesn't do any stripping of parameters (or I would say "schemes"). But, it can be done easily with `replace()` or `substring()`